# Bizzare rendering issue with Intel 965G graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg

I've recently revived an older desktop computer, which previously had Ubuntu 14.04 on it but hadn't been used for at least a year. I've managed to get 15.10 onto it, and it all went well and boots properly.

However, often when I'm using it I get very weird graphical errors, like these:
[image: Synaptic rendering error]
[image: Nautilus rendering error]

This happens in almost all windows, and even within Firefox on images in websites. Strangely, scrolling past the broken image in Firefox and bringing it back still didn't change the rendering - it's quite persistent. It doesn't happen all the time though, the system is sometimes usable.

The system has an older Intel 965 graphics chipset.

Has anyone else seen this before? What is going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: A quick search of the web does not show anything recent.  You could try using the [oibaf drivers](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)

Comment: Added the PPA from the link, it seems to have maybe improved the problem but it's still there. Perhaps it's not actually an improvement at all, I just have an observer bias. But anyway, thanks for the hint. 

It might just be a faulty GPU, it is nearly 10 years old. I ran memtest and it passed, so the RAM is alright at least.